# Raycaster intersectObjects always return empty array

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to get the intersections of a raycaster, but no matter what it always returns an empty array.

How I add objects to an objects array:

```
var obstructionGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(6,5,0.5);
var obstructionMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000} );
var obstruction1 = new THREE.Mesh(obstructionGeom, obstructionMaterial);
obstruction1.position.set(-10,0,-15);
obstruction1.name = "obstruction";
scene.add(obstruction1);
obstructions.push(obstruction1);
```

Then I call intersectObjects like this:

```
let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.set(new THREE.Vector3(), obstruction1.position);
let intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(obstructions);
```

Notice that I cast the raycaster in the direction of the mesh's position and still returns empty. What could be causing this behaviour ?

Comment: You're spelling obstruction differently in different spots. Also, learn to use the chrome debugger and single step through code like this, while hovering the mouse over every variable and parameter to make sure it contains what you expect it to...

Comment: Just a small remark. For direction, you're using the position of an obstruction, whereas it has to be a normalized vector. [Documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Raycaster.set) And could you explain, what is `new THREE.Vector()`? We have `THREE.Vector2()`, `THREE.Vector3()` and `THREE.Vector4()` only in Three.js

Comment: I'm sorry, I was translating construccion to construction to make it more "english friendly" and forgot to rename a few variables, but that is not the problem. Also I checked that objects contain what they're suposed to. And the Vector() is a Vector3, that is not the problem either. but thanks for the replies

Comment: @prisoner849 I normalized the vector and still didn't work, always return empty even if I cast it directly to the object. I also tried intersectObject(obstruction1) with the raycaster set from origin and direction to obstruction1.position.clone().normalize() and still returns empty array.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't know what was causing the problem, but I fixed it by getting the intersections outside of componentDidMount() where the scene is rendered. I guess that makes sense right? I'm not suposed to intersect something that is not there. I feel dumb now, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following lines of code to trace the changes.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < intersections.length; i++ ) {

            intersections[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
            console.log(intersections[i].object)

        }
```

also try to change the following spelling:
**obstruccionGeom**, **obstruccionMaterial** to **obstructionGeom** , **obstructionMaterial**

Comment: I forgot to change those variables in this post because I translated obstruccion to obstruction, but that is not the problem. Thanks for the reply but that for loop you mention won't work because intersections.length is always 0

Comment: yes I did, the arrow is pointing right at the object I need to intersect.

Comment: this is what the arrow looks like, the intersection1 object is the rectangular figure at the top. https://ibb.co/hNRewy